# How to remove the reaction when a user reacts to the message? - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am developing a bot, and in the command "help" I want that when the user reacts to an emoji, his reaction goes away and a new EMBED appears.

```
informacaoL.on('collect', r => {

        const embedinformacao = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} - Ajuda`)
            .setDescription(`⭐ **UTEIS**
            !ajuda - Exibe o menu de ajuda.
            !server - Mostra status do servidor.
            !user - Mostra o perfil do usuário.
            !bot - Mostra informações sobre mim.
            !sugerir \`<sugestão>\` - Crie uma sugestão para melhorar nosso servidor.
            !avatar - Mostra o avatar de um usuário ou do próprio usuário que usou o comando.
            !invites - Mostra o rank de convites.
            !lembrete \`<tempo>\` \`<lembrete>\` - Te lembra de algo importante.
            !notificar - Recebe a tag  NOTIFICAR (!notificar) e recebe novidades do servidor.
            !desnotificar - Remove a tag  NOTIFICAR (!notificar).
            !rank - Mostra o rank de XP.
            !topmoney - Mostra o rank de money.
            !ping - Mostra o delay bot-servidor.
            !toprep - Mostra o rank de recomendações.
            !codigo - Usado para enviar códigos snippets na sala  snippets de códigos.
            !imgur \`<img>\` - Faz upload de uma imagem para o Imgur.
     `)
            .setColor("#00ff44")
            .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
        msg.edit(embedinformacao)
    })
```

Comment: This might help you: [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions), particularly the `removeAll()` method from ReactionManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the reaction, just do `<Reaction>.remove()`. If you have this in a reaction listener, you should have the reaction defined, and that should be the single reaction which would be removed. Very simple yet very helpful